# When I run wordcount application it never finish

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, word-count

I need help for running wordcount application in Hadoop. I work on Multi Node clusters, I want to run it on my main(master) node.

I make folder for input and copy .txt to that folder, it works great. [1](https://prnt.sc/m1eq3s), [2](http://prntscr.com/m1eqmw)

Now I need to run mapreduce which is done using eclipse.
Run with:

```
hadoop jar WordCount.jar WordCount /input /output
```

When I run it I get:

```
/input
/output
18/12/30 19:50:13 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at 
/0.0.0.0:8032
18/12/30 19:50:13 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line 
option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your 
application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
18/12/30 19:50:14 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process 
: 1
18/12/30 19:50:14 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
18/12/30 19:50:14 INFO Configuration.deprecation: 
yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. 
Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled
18/12/30 19:50:14 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: 
job_1546180801267_1648
18/12/30 19:50:15 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application 
application_1546180801267_1648
18/12/30 19:50:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://ec2- 
3-82-16-179.compute- 
1.amazonaws.com:8088/proxy/application_1546180801267_1648/
18/12/30 19:50:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1546180801267_1648
```

I listen to a lot of tutorial, in every tutorial they do some things and they get same INFO, but after that map and reduce run, in my situation it does not run.

Here is my .profile [3](http://prntscr.com/m1et8r) :

Here is yarn-site.xml [4](http://prntscr.com/m1eto8) :

Mapred-site.xml [5](http://prntscr.com/m1etxs) :

hdfs-site.xml [6](http://prntscr.com/m1euk4) :

core-site.xml [7](http://prntscr.com/m1euvi), [8](http://prntscr.com/m1ev3k) :

Please help me with this, I am trying to solve it for two days but without any good result.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Hadoop are you using? and all your configs has "thisnamenode". wondering if you intentionally change it to this value or your actual config's also has same value? I see some configs are incorrect but before I post answer, I want to know which version of Hadoop are you using?

Comment: @NaveenNelamali I use Hadoop-2.7.7. I change it to "thisnamenode"